# iterate with a conditional within a loop in python

Tags: python, list, loops, return

I am learning Python and got stucked on one of the exercises. We have to convert camelCase into snake_case. I tried with a conditional in a loop:

```
camelCase = input("camelCase: ")
for c in camelCase:
    if c.islower():
        return c
    elif c.isupper():
        return ("_" + c.lower())

print("snake_case:" + c)
```

But I realized I didn´t understand how return works.

Now I tried making a list:

```
camelCase = input("camelCase: ")
snake_case = []
for c in camelCase:
    if c.islower():
        snake_case.append(c)
    elif c.isupper():
        snake_case.append("_" + c.lower())

print("snake_case:", snake_case)
```

But I don´t know how to get it like a string (word), it comes out like that.

```
camelCase: firstName
snake_case: ['f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', '_n', 'a', 'm', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done the hard part, now all you need to do is get it into a string.

`str.join` is meant for that: you can just use:

```py
print("snake_case:", ''.join(snake_case))
```

to join the elements in your list.

From the [documentation of `str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

> **`str.join(iterable)`**
>
> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable. [...] The separator between elements is the string providing this method.

---

Note: you asked about `return`. That is only for functions (see below). If it is used outside of a function, an error will be raised.

Here is an example use of `return`:

```py
def add_one(num):
    return num + 1

print(add_one(5)) # Outputs 6
```

You might want to check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) out to learn more about functions.

Comment: I tried this one out, but it raises an SyntaxError. (Invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?)
The problem seams to be ''.join()
I tried with "" / '' and puting a , inbetween, but nothing worked

Comment: @Anarres - It worked for me, are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: I thouht so, but then I copy pasted yours and it worked. Thanks!!

Comment: @Anarres don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the check mark (✔️) if you found it helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution is creating a list and appending a string for each letter. If you want to have a string result, simple create an empty string and **concatenate** a string for each letter to that variable. Your solution may look something like:

```py
camelCase = input("camelCase: ")
snake_case = ""
for c in camelCase:
    if c.islower():
        # 'x += 1' is the same as 'x = x + 1'
        snake_case += c
    elif c.isupper():
        snake_case += "_" + c.lower()

print("snake_case:", snake_case)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you can just use strings rather than an explicit character array, and append to them with a +=.

```
camelCase = input("camelCase: ")
snake_case = ""
for c in camelCase:
    if c.islower():
        snake_case += c
    elif c.isupper():
        snake_case += "_" + c.lower()
print("snake_case:", snake_case)
```

This gives you what you want:

```
camelCase: firstName
snake_case: first_name
```